# How to expose non-model module methods via Django Rest Framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am using [Django Rest Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org) to create an API. There are model classes such as `City` which are exposed via the API. Now I created a `utils` module with a few useful methods:

```
# city/utils.py

def distance_between_cities(city1, city2):
    return city1.distance(city2)
```

I want to expose the example method `distance_between_cities` as an API endpoint. So I started off by creating a view:

```
# city/views.py
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from . import utils

class DistanceView(APIView):

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        city1 = request.query_params.get('city1', None)
        city2 = request.query_params.get('city2', None)
        distance = utils.distance_between_cities(city1, city2)
        distance_hash = {'distance': distance}
        return Response(distance_hash, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Then I tried to register a route:

```
# city/urls.py
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter
from . import views

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'distance', views.DistanceView)
```

When I visit the website the following **error** is shown:

> `base_name` argument not specified, and could not automatically determine the name from the viewset, as it does not have a `.queryset` attribute.

I would like to see the endpoint in the website rendered by DRF similar to other (model related) endpoints.

[image: DRF API website]

Finally, I would like to access the endpoint via:

```
http://localhost:8000/api/cities/distance.json?city1=23&city1=42
```

I tried to inspect the API via *curl*:

```
$ curl -X HEAD -i http://localhost:8000/api/cities/distance.json?city1=23&city2=42
```

This is the response header:

```
HTTP/1.0 404 NOT FOUND
Date: Fri, 09 Oct 2015 16:45:06 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.4.3
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept, Cookie
Allow: GET, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS
```

---

### Useful links

- [Tutorial 2: Requests and Responses](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/2-requests-and-responses/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need the new entry point to be listed, you'll need to inherit from a ViewSet (note that I'm not speaking about ModelViewSet).

I wrote a short guide + sample project on how to do that here: https://medium.com/@linovia/django-rest-framework-viewset-when-you-don-t-have-a-model-335a0490ba6f

You won't need all the ViewSet methods, probably just the list one according to your comments.

Answer (score 0):

in your urls.py, you're giving router.register() a DistanceView, which is of type APIView, But you'll have to specify a ViewSet for that.

django-rest-framework can only determine url mapping for ViewSets. So instead you can manually map the url, like you would do with default django apps.

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'distance', views.DistanceView),
]
```

Comment: The error is gone. But I cannot see the API endpoint. Is this url then still being displayed on the website `http://localhost:8000` rending the API?